# steamlit results in 'AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute '_infrequent_enabled''

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, streamlit

I had run the following OneHotEncoder code on jupyter notebook, it's fine:

ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('col_tnf',OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,drop='first'),0,1,3,8,11])],remainder='passthrough')

It's running and gives the output,
while the same, I am running using PyCharm as a Streamlit app, its throwing error as
AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute '_infrequent_enabled'

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolve. You need to update the sklearn version same as the version you are using in jupyter notebook